# Error in importing hive packages

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

I am new to hive's udf. I have downloaded "`apache-hive-2.1.0-bin`" and configured build path of my project to `apache-hive-2.1.0-bin\lib` (all jars).

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;  // <= I am not able to import this package.

public class replace extends UDF {

    private Text result = new Text();

    public Text evaluate(String str, String str1, String str2) {
        String rep = str.replace(str1, str2);
        result.set(rep);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need the `hadoop-core.jar` -- [How do I compile a Hive UDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019465/how-do-i-compile-a-hive-udf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following in lib path hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar

It will be available in

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
```